# Scroll a TextView in TableLayout into the visible area of screen

Tags: java, android-widget, scrollview

how do I get a `TextView` into the visible area of a screen by scrolling a `ScrollView`, if the `TextView` is not a direct child of the `ScrollView`?

I've got a `LinearLayout` view that has a `TextView` at the top, then a `ScrollView` and below a `Button`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/s"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/t"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/r" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/a"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/b"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/c"/>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

That generated a wholly filled screen with the label at the top border, the button at the bottom border, and a table between it; depending on how many rows this table has, you can scroll it or not.

The contents of the table are generated by Java code, I just added one row as example of what is inserted there.

I now need to make sure a certain row (not necessarily the last one) is visible by scrolling vertically. I can access every element from `s` to `c`, but I can't figure out the code to make the `ScrollView s` scroll at all.

I tried `requestChildRectangleOnScreen`, `scrollBy` and, `scrollTo`, but possibly always with the wrong arguments.

For now I don't care whether `TextView a` is vertically centered or at the bottom or top border, it would indeed be great if it was visible at all. X-scroll should stay 0, ideally (i. e. leftmost position).

In case this is important: this function is only called when the user enters the screen with a special Intent that's telling the screen to scroll to `TableRow` x (it's just to show the latest change).

If you need even more information, please ask.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed that I called the function directly from a sub call of `onCreate`. This meant the layout wasn't done yet, thus all scrolling was done before the elements had a height and so it scrolled by 0 pixels.

The solution is to use `View.post(Runnable r)`:

```
ScrollView s = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.s);
TextView a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
s.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int[] location = new int[2];
        a.getLocationInWindow(location);
        int y = location[1];
        s.getLocationInWindow(location);
        s.scrollTo(0, y-location[1]); // or some other calculation
    }
});
```